# help with hangman sorting

Tags: java, sorting

i need to sort my my letters guessed alphabetically. i know i need to use array.sort but i cant figure out how. i also need to make it so that the program asks if you want to play again after the game is over and i've tried to make it work but i cant seem to get it right. please help. thank you

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Random;


public class DRMproject2 
{

    public static void main( String[] args ) 
    {
        HangmanSession hangmanSession = new HangmanSession();
        hangmanSession.play();
    }
}

class HangmanSession 
{
    private Player player;
    private Words secretWord;
    private LetterBox letterBox;
    private int wrongGuessCount = 6;


    public HangmanSession() 
    {
        player = new Player();
        player.askName();
        secretWord = new Words();
        letterBox = new LetterBox();
    }

    private void printState() 
    {
        letterBox.print();
        System.out.print( "Hidden word : " );
        secretWord.print();
        System.out.print( "Tries left: " + wrongGuessCount + "\nguess letter: " );
    }

    public void play() 
    {
        boolean bool = true;
        while( true ) 
        {
            bool = true;
            printState();
            char ch = player.guess();
            if( letterBox.contains( ch ) ) {
                System.out.println( "Try again, you've already used the letter " + ch );
                bool = false;
            }
            if( bool ) 
            {
                if( secretWord.guess( ch ) )
                {
                    System.out.println( "You have found the letter " + ch );
                }
                else {
                    wrongGuessCount--;
                }
                if( wrongGuessCount < 1 )
                    lose();
                if( secretWord.found() )
                    win();
            }
        }
    }

    public void win() 
    {
        System.out.println( "Congratulations " + player +  ", you win!" );
        System.exit( 0 );
    }

    public void lose() 
    {
        System.out.println( "Sorry " + player + ", you lose. Better luck next time!" );
        System.exit( 0 );
    }

}

class Words 
{
    private String fv;
    private StringBuffer pv;
    private int found = 0;
    {
        String Words[] = new String[23];

        Words[0] = "carbon";
        Words[1] = "dictionary";
        Words[2] = "restaurant";
        Words[3] = "television";
        Words[4] = "responsible";
        Words[5] = "technology";
        Words[6] = "computer";
        Words[7] = "communicate";
        Words[8] = "automobile";
        Words[9] = "coffee";
        Words[10] = "federation";
        Words[11] = "exaggerate";
        Words[12] = "cappuccino";
        Words[13] = "macintosh";
        Words[14] = "apple";
        Words[15] = "microsoft";
        Words[16] = "lighter";
        Words[17] = "shark";
        Words[18] = "bunker";
        Words[19] = "argument";
        Words[20] = "playstation";
        Words[21] = "parrot";
        Words[22] = "canine";

        Random random = new Random();
        int randomWord = random.nextInt(22);
        String[] displayLetters = new String[Words[randomWord].length()];
        fv = Words[randomWord]; 
        pv = new StringBuffer(fv.length()); 
        for (int i = 0; i < displayLetters.length; i++)
        {
            displayLetters[i] = "_";
            pv.append('_'); 
        }

    } 

    public boolean found() 
    {
        System.out.println( "Letters found:" + found + "/" + fv.length() );
        return ( found == fv.length() );
    }

    public boolean guess( char c ) 
    {
        int index = fv.indexOf( c );
        if( index == -1 )
            return false;
        else {
            found = found + findOccurances( c );
        return true;
    }
}

private int findOccurances( char c )
{
    int idx = fv.indexOf( c );
    pv.setCharAt( idx, fv.charAt( idx ) );
    int counter = 1;
    while( idx != -1 ) {
        int index = fv.indexOf( c, idx + 1 );
        idx = index;
        if( idx != -1 ) {
            counter++;
            pv.setCharAt( idx, fv.charAt( idx ) );
        }
    }
    return counter;
}

public void print() 
{
    System.out.println( pv );
}

}


class Player 
{
    private String name = " ";
    public void askName() 
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Hangman");
        System.out.print( "Player, enter your name: " );
        name = input();
    }

    public char guess()
    {
        return input().charAt( 0 );
    }

    private String input() 
    {
        String str = " ";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( System.in ) );
        try 
        {
            str = br.readLine();
        }
        catch( IOException ex )
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return str;
    }
    public String toString() 
    {
        return name;
    }
}

class LetterBox 
{
    private char[] lbox = new char[24];
    private int counter = 0;

    public boolean contains( char c ) 
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < counter; i++ )
        {
            if( lbox[i] == c )
                return true;
        }
        lbox[counter] = c;
        counter++;
        return false;
    }
    public void print() 
    {
        System.out.print( "LetterBox: " );
        for( int i = 0; i < counter; i++ ) 
        {
            System.out.print( lbox[i] );
        }
        System.out.println( " " );
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any reference to Array.sort in your code...? As for repeating games, how about a loop in your main method that repeatedly creates a new session, plays it and then asks if you want to play again?

Comment: i couldn't figure out where to put the arrays.sort in the code to make it sort the guessed letters

Comment: @user you'd just put it right after you add a new character. Besides that, using a sorted datastructure like `SortedSet` would be preferable, as already stated.

Answer (score 1):

To resume the program and play another game you shouldn't call this in `win()` or `lose()`:
`System.exit( 0 );`

Instead employ a loop and ask the user what he wants to do, e.g. `play again` or `exit`.
For `play again` reset the game's state and start a new run.

To sort the char array, just call `Arrays.sort(lbox)`. However, this might put the unitialized to the front. Instead you might want to use a `SortedSet<Character>` which already provides a `contains` method and would sort the characters by their natural order  (Note the use of class `Character` not the primitive here, although through auto(un)boxing you should be able to pass primitives as well, just not in the declaration).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you meant by the array sorting but using array.sort will sort an array this link might shed some light on it.

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0343.html

As for the playing again you need to change your win method to ask the user if they wish to play again check the input and then if they do wish to play again you should be able to call play() again.

```
public void win() {
 System.out.println( "Congratulations " + player +  ", you win!" );
 ask to play again
 get input
 check input
 if want to play again
   play()
 else 
   exit    
}
```

Comment: I'd not put that to `win()`. How about making another try after losing? ;)

Comment: Very true, I'm not thinking this morning :), you could place that code into an game end method that would display you win or you lose and then check if you wish to play again.

Answer (score 0):

here is ur letterbox impl

```
class LetterBox {

    private SortedSet<Byte> data = new TreeSet<Byte>();

    public int getSize() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public void add(char c) {
        data.add(Byte.valueOf((byte) c));

    }

    public boolean contains(char c) {
        return data.contains(Byte.valueOf((byte) c));
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.print("LetterBox: ");
        for (Byte _char : data) {
            System.out.print(((char) _char.byteValue()));
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }


}
```